# What happens when I import firebase from my firebaseConfig.js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Not a problem/bug, but I have the following questions about the Firebase config file below:

```
firebaseconfig.js

import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
  databaseURL: "YOUR_DATABASE_URL",
  projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "YOUR_MESSAGING_ID"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export default firebase;
```

When I import firebase from this config file (firebaseconfig.js), does it run the entire firebase.js file and *then* import the firebase object each time, or does it just give me the firebase object at the end? If it's the first answer, then does that mean that multiple instances of firebase app get initialized? If it's the second answer, then when does the code preceding "export default firebase" get executed and not-executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you require or import some javascript code, it only gets executed once, no matter how many times it's required or imported.  The resulting export is essentially a singleton that's shared across all modules that uses it.

Comment: Thank you! This helps clarifies things - I was trying to understand if this behaved like a singleton.